# Proving that $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+a\pi\right)=0$ when a is an integer

Tags: trigonometry, alternative-proof

So, I'm having a bit of trouble proving this. I tried using the sum formula, but the problem with that is that I end up having to prove that $\sin \left(a\pi\right)$ is equal to $0$. This is kind of counter-productive as it's essentially what I'm trying to do in the question! Is there a better way of proving it by avoiding this?

I do get a $0\times\cos(k\pi)$ during the proof, but I don't need to do anything with it as it becomes $0$ anyway. However, along with that I get a $1\times\sin(k\pi)$, which is why I'm asking this question.

Comment: Wat is your definition of $\cos(\theta)$? If you define it by it's power series these things reduce to properties of exponentials.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Please give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** using the fact that $\cos(\pi)=-1$ and $\sin(\pi)=0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\cos(x+\pi)
&=\cos(x)\cos(\pi)-\sin(x)\sin(\pi)\\
&=-\cos(x)
\end{align}
$$
now use induction and the fact that $\cos\left(\frac\pi2\right)=0$.

Comment: Just a quick question though: this would only be sufficient proof for the positive integers, right? It wouldn't help me for negative integers. Would I need to look at the cases of positive and negative integers separately, and use two cases of induction?

Comment: $$\begin{align} \cos(x-\pi) &=\cos(x)\cos(\pi)+\sin(x)\sin(\pi)\\ &= -\cos(x) \end{align}$$ yes, two cases of induction.

Comment: Thank you very much, again.

Comment: Or use the fact $\cos(-y) = \cos(y)$, and therefore $\cos(\pi - y)=-\cos(y)$, to deal with all negative integers. For $\cos(\frac\pi2 +a\pi)$, with $a<0$, let $y=\frac\pi2-a\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

$sin (n\pi)=0$ for $n\in I $ thats all now use $\sin (x)=\frac {e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i} $ to complete the proof

Comment: That is correct, but wouldn't I need to prove this as well? In essence this would be as if I were stating the question itself is equal to 0.

Comment: Graph of $sin (x)$ is the proof itself

Comment: the graph isn't a proof, look at the series for the function

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is, the graph of $\cos(x+\pi/2)$ could also be the proof :)

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner My question was already answered, but would it be possible for you to give me a hint on how to do that using a series for the function? I cannot for the life of me figure it out.